# clear background image from input button after 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using this code to set a background image to my page for 10 seconds after that image is cleared but when i reload the page i have the last image used on the background.

How to clear the image once and for all?

Another problem is that i am using this background button in a drawing web app and sometimes after changing the background the app freezes.

```js
$(switchBackground);

var oFReader = new FileReader(),
    rFilter = /^(?:image\/bmp|image\/cis\-cod|image\/gif|image\/ief|image\/jpeg|image\/jpeg|image\/jpeg|image\/pipeg|image\/png|image\/svg\+xml|image\/tiff|image\/x\-cmu\-raster|image\/x\-cmx|image\/x\-icon|image\/x\-portable\-anymap|image\/x\-portable\-bitmap|image\/x\-portable\-graymap|image\/x\-portable\-pixmap|image\/x\-rgb|image\/x\-xbitmap|image\/x\-xpixmap|image\/x\-xwindowdump)$/i;

oFReader.onload = function(oFREvent) {
  localStorage.setItem('b', oFREvent.target.result);
  switchBackground();
};

function switchBackground() {
  $('body').css('background-image', "url(" + localStorage.getItem('b') + ')');    
}

function loadImageFile(testEl) {
  if (! testEl.files.length) { return; }
  var oFile = testEl.files[0];
  if (!rFilter.test(oFile.type)) { alert("You must select a valid image file!"); return; }
  oFReader.readAsDataURL(oFile);
}
```

```html
<input id="test" type="file" onchange="loadImageFile(this)" />
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6ph4bf90/)

Comment: `for 10 seconds after that image is cleared ` I can't see where you defined this.

Comment: You are setting a Local Storage item to store the background image and then loading it again when the page loads. There isn't anything clearing the background from Local Storage after 10 seconds. I'm not sure why you are using Local Storage anyway if you are only setting a background image for 10 seconds and removing it.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to clear background after 10 second so please change function as per below.

```
var obj;
function switchBackground() {
  $('body').css('background-image', "url(" + localStorage.getItem('b') + ')');   
  clearTimeout(obj);
  obj = setTimeout(function(){
              $('body').css('background-image','none');   
            }, 10000);
}
```

and if you also want to remove image in local storage after 10 second the so delete jstorage script in setTimeout function

Comment: i tried     function switchBackground() {
 
      $('body').css('background-image', "url(" + localStorage.getItem('b') + ')');
   
   var delay=10000; //1 minute

setTimeout(function () {
   document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'none';



   
 var delay=0;
}, delay);

    }

Comment: If you not clearTimeout so may be chances of conflict timeout otherwise it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
localStorage.clear();
```

i think it solved my problem